# AngularJS html5mode = true error when I access directly url with params

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, angularjs, symfony

I have an application developed with Angularjs and Symfony 2, I enabled the html5 mode to get friendly urls.

The application is integrated with Symfony 2.3 to response at services.

app.js

```
 .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$provide' , function($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$provide) {

      $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
            $delegate.history = false;
            return $delegate;
        });

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/quienes_somos', {templateUrl: 'views/quienes_somos.html', controller: 'QuienesSomosController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/ubicanos', {templateUrl: 'views/ubicanos.html', controller: 'UbicanosController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/ubicanos/:route', {templateUrl: 'views/ubicanos.html', controller: 'UbicanosController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/catalogo', {templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/catalogo/:category', {templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/catalogo/:category/:productid', {templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/catalogo/results',{templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/noticias', {templateUrl: 'views/noticias.html', controller: 'NoticiasController'});

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

The problem occurs when I try to access directly putting the route and params of a category.

> http://plastimex.localhost/catalogo/tablilla-plastica

Angularjs does not load. But the other routes works correctly.

*Not working routes*

```
 $routeProvider.when('/catalogo/:category', {templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController' });

 $routeProvider.when('/catalogo/:category/:productid', {templateUrl: 'views/catalogo.html', controller: 'CatalogoController'});
```

also I set this on index.html `<base href="/index.html" />`

This is the .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have made modifications to the htaccess to get it works but not lucky. It rolled back.

Any idea? Please.
thank you.

Comment: I recently had an issue with a route with parameter not working. It started working when I changed it from /foo/:id to /foo/:id/bar – don't know why :)

Comment: Hello @aweibell  Last week The problem solved when I changed all my index.html content to a Symfony View .twig, there was a routing conflict and the Htaccess was not working. Now it's working.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have html5mode set to true, but the example URL you mention looks like you're using a hashbang. Is this just a typo?

```
http://plastimex.localhost/index.html#/catalogo/tablilla-plastica
```

Should be

```
http://plastimex.localhost/catalogo/tablilla-plastica
```

Sorry, I would have left this as a comment but I don't have the points.

Link to the relevant docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Comment: Hello Matt, 
It's ok, I used http://plastimex.localhost/catalogo/tablilla-plastica also but not lucky. I use http://plastimex.localhost/ubicanos and It works correctly. I don't know what is the problem when I use params.